# Add a legend to the scatterplot

Tags: r

How would I add a legend to the following scatterplot

```
library(UsingR) 
data(galton) 

freqData <- as.data.frame(table(galton$child, galton$parent))
names(freqData) <- c("child", "parent", "freq")
plot(as.numeric(as.vector(freqData$parent)), 
      as.numeric(as.vector(freqData$child)),
      pch = 21, col = "black", bg = "lightblue",
      cex = .15 * freqData$freq, 
      xlab = "parent", ylab = "child")
```

Comment: This is not `ggplot2` code, but rather base R graphics. See `?legend`. Here is a silly example to get you started: `plot(1:10, 1:10); legend("bottomright", legend="this", pch=1)`

Comment: freqData <- as.data.frame(table(galton$child, galton$parent))
> names(freqData) <- c("child", "parent", "freq")
> plot(as.numeric(as.vector(freqData$parent)), 
+      as.numeric(as.vector(freqData$child)),
+      pch = 21, col = "black", bg = "lightblue",
+      cex = .10 * freqData$freq, 
+      xlab = "parent", ylab = "child")
> legend("bottomright","(freqData)",pch=21, title="freqData")

Comment: the legend is not including the indication based on size of the circles

Comment: This is a different question than the one you asked above. Perhaps you should add a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including a Legend in a Scatterplot where size of plot indicates frequency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169054/including-a-legend-in-a-scatterplot-where-size-of-plot-indicates-frequency)